# Unable to Delete User Document Using AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a Flutter application that uses Firestore for database operations. In one part of the app, I have a list of users, and I want to implement a delete functionality using an AlertDialog. However, when I tap the "Delete" option in the PopupMenuButton, nothing happens, and the user is not deleted.

**Code Description:**

I have a `Users` widget that fetches user data from Firestore and displays it in a `ListView`. Each user item is represented as a `ListTile` with a `PopupMenuButton` containing "Edit" and "Delete" options.

```
trailing: PopupMenuButton(
  itemBuilder: (context) {
    return [
      PopupMenuItem(
        value: 'edit',
        child: const Text('Edit', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0)),
        onTap: () {
          // Edit functionality works correctly
        },
      ),
      PopupMenuItem(
        value: 'delete',
        child: const Text('Delete', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0)),
        onTap: () {
          // Delete functionality is not working as expected
        },
      ),
    ];
  },
),
```

For the "Delete" option, I'm using an `AlertDialog` named `DeleteUserDialog`, which is supposed to delete the user upon confirmation.

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: _deleteUser, // Calls _deleteUser function
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
  ),
  child: const Text('Delete'),
),
...

Future<void> _deleteUser() async {
  try {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(widget.userId).delete();
    // Show success message and close the dialog
  } catch (error) {
    // Show error message
  }
}
```

Issue:

The issue is that when I tap the "Delete" option in the PopupMenuButton, the user is not deleted, and there is no error message displayed. The _deleteUser function seems to be called, but the document deletion does not take place.

Expected Outcome:

Upon tapping "Delete," I expect the DeleteUserDialog to delete the user document from Firestore and display a success message. If there's an error, it should display an error message.

Question:

What could be causing the user deletion to fail in this scenario?

How can I properly implement the delete functionality using an AlertDialog and Firestore in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your context, it will be like

```dart
_showDeleteDialog([String msg = '']) async {
      await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text(msg),
        ),
      );
    }

    __deleteUser() async {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      String message = '';
      try {
        //...your code here
        //you can add your own logic here
        message = 'User deleted successfully';
        // Show success message and close the dialog
      } catch (error) {
        // Show error message and close the dialog
        message = 'Error deleting user ${error.toString()}}';
      }
      _showDeleteDialog(message);
    }
```

And call the method like `onTap: __deleteUser,`.